# How can the C++ Preprocessor be used on strings?

Tags: c++, string, c-preprocessor

The preprocessor can be used to replace certain keywords with other words using `#define`. For example I could do `#define name "George"` and every time the preprocessor finds 'name' in the program it will replace it with "George".

However, this only seems to work with code. How could I do this with strings and text? For example if I print "Hello I am name" to the screen, I want 'name' to be replaced with "George" even though it is in a string and not code.

I do not want to manually search the string for keywords and then replace them, but instead want to use the preprocessor to just switch the words.

Is this possible? If so how?

I am using C++ but C solutions are also acceptable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
#define name "George"

printf("Hello I am " name "\n");
```

Adjacent string literals are concatenated in C and C++.

**Quotes from C and C++ Standard:**

For C (quoting C99, but C11 has something similar in 6.4.5p5):

> (C99, 6.4.5p5) "In translation phase 6, the multibyte character sequences specified by any sequence of adjacent character and identically-prefixed string literal tokens are concatenated into a single multibyte character sequence."

For C++:

> (C++11, 2.14.5p13) "In translation phase 6 (2.2), adjacent string literals are concatenated."

EDIT: as requested, add quotes from C and C++ Standard. Thanks to @MatteoItalia for the C++11 quote.

Comment: this becomes `printf("Hello I am" "George" "\n");`, which is invalid.

Comment: This is perfectly valid in C and the implementation has to compile it.

Comment: No, HunterMcMillen, Mr.TAMER, this compiles. The preprocessor will concatenate strings.

Comment: @Mr.TAMER Will this even expand? I would expect a compiler error.

Comment: I'd be happier with `print("%s", "Hello I am " name " \n");`. But anyway, +1 for concatenation.

Comment: my mistake this does compile, with gcc atleast

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: even simpler: `puts("Hello I am " name);`.

Comment: It's guaranteed it works, it's mandated by the standard: "In translation phase 6 (2.2), adjacent string literals are concatenated." (C++11, [lex.string] ¶13) Notice that the concatenation is not done by the preprocessor, but by the processor (the preprocessor ends its work at phase 4).

Comment: Here's the code working on [ideone](http://ideone.com/HZla1). I'm pretty sure that's `gcc`. Works fine on my desktop too. `gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3`  @HunterMcMillen, can you copy your code somewhere, maybe ideone.com ?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid the canonical K&R version of hello world is `printf("hello, world");` not `printf("%s\n", "hello, world");`.

Comment: @ouah, there's a risk that some day `name` will have `%` in it somewhere. But then again, who would name their child `%` ? :-) So yeah, I suppose it's OK.

Comment: @ouah: the canonical K&R version of hello world doesn't have pieces of the format string scattered around in several places.

Comment: @ouah: Perhaps it would be clearer to put Matteo's quote form the standards in your answer for those who come later.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I always wondered, though, why the canonical HW isn't `puts("Hello, world.");` or `fputs("Hello, world.\n", stdout);`. Those are much closer to what's really intended, although I guess you have to give K&R a "+1" for exposing the ubiquitous `printf` early on.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think that they probably chose to use only it from the beginning to allow outputting from the start any type, introducing the other IO functions later in the book.

Answer (score 7):

```
#define name "George"

printf("Hello I am %s\n", name);
```

Here name will be replaced by "George"

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that the preprocessor will (wisely) not replace tokens that are *inside string literals*.

So you must either use a function like `printf` or a variable rather than the preprocessor, or pull the token out of the string like so:

```
#include <iostream>

#define name "George"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Hello I am " << name << std::endl;
}
```